# Вызов пайтоновских скриптов из кода с++

Tags: c++, python

Прочитал статью на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/167261/) об использовании Python в многопоточном приложении `с++` с использованием субинтерпретаторов. При этом, как заявляется в статье, это позволяет обеспечить "чистую многопоточность", тобишь субинтрепритаторы не лочатся глобальным `GIL` (прошу прощения за тавтологию), а работают параллельно. В общем, решил попробовать и написал вот такой код:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <unordered_map>

class PyMainThread final {
public:
  PyMainThread()
      : mainThreadState_{nullptr} {
    ::Py_Initialize();
    ::PyEval_InitThreads();

    mainGIL_         = ::PyGILState_Ensure();
    mainThreadState_ = ::PyEval_SaveThread();
  }

  ~PyMainThread() {
    ::PyEval_RestoreThread(mainThreadState_);
    ::PyGILState_Release(mainGIL_);
  }

  PyMainThread(const PyMainThread &) = delete;
  PyMainThread &operator=(const PyMainThread &) = delete;

private:
  ::PyGILState_STATE mainGIL_;
  ::PyThreadState *  mainThreadState_;
};

static std::mutex mutex;

class PySubThread final {
public:
  PySubThread()
      : mainThreadState_{nullptr}
      , subThreadState_{nullptr}
      , newInterpreterThread_{nullptr} {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    mainGIL_         = ::PyGILState_Ensure();
    mainThreadState_ = ::PyThreadState_Get();

    newInterpreterThread_ = ::Py_NewInterpreter();
    ::PyThreadState_Swap(newInterpreterThread_);

    subThreadState_ = ::PyEval_SaveThread();
    subGIL_         = ::PyGILState_Ensure();
  }

  ~PySubThread() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    ::PyGILState_Release(subGIL_);
    ::PyEval_RestoreThread(subThreadState_);

    ::Py_EndInterpreter(newInterpreterThread_);
    ::PyThreadState_Swap(mainThreadState_);

    ::PyGILState_Release(mainGIL_);
  }

  PySubThread(const PySubThread &) = delete;
  PySubThread &operator=(const PySubThread &) = delete;

private:
  ::PyGILState_STATE mainGIL_;
  ::PyGILState_STATE subGIL_;

  ::PyThreadState *mainThreadState_;
  ::PyThreadState *subThreadState_;

  ::PyThreadState *newInterpreterThread_;
};

std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, std::unique_ptr<PySubThread>> pyThreads;
std::mutex                                                        pyM;

void foo(const std::string &pythonFile, int iterationCount) {
  volatile PySubThread subThread;
  for (int i = 0; i < iterationCount; ++i) {
    try {
      // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{1000});
      boost::python::object import = boost::python::import("__main__");
      boost::python::object result =
          boost::python::exec_file(pythonFile.c_str(), import.attr("__dict__"));
    } catch (boost::python::error_already_set &) {
      ::PyErr_Print();
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 4) {
    std::cerr << "you must set script, threads and count of iterations"
              << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  volatile PyMainThread mainThread;

  std::list<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < std::atoi(argv[2]); ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back(foo, argv[1], argv[3]);
  }

  for (auto &i : threads) {
    i.join();
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

а это питоновский скрипт, который дёргается в коде:

```py
import time


def caculate(a, b):
  return a + b


def main():
  print("sleep 2 seconds ...")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("... and calculate")
  return caculate(-10, 20)


main()
```

```
# cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(tmp)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python37 REQUIRED)
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
  Boost::boost
  ${Python3_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  Threads::Threads
  )
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

При запуске в несколько потоков все работает, как и говорилось в статье, НО! Обратите внимание на 88ую строку в `с++` коде. Эта строка ставит поток с пайтоновским субинтерпретатором на паузу в течение одной секунды. Если ее раскомментировать, то программа зависнет и никогда не завершится. При этом засечь место, где программа останавливается (ИМХО это получение GIL в конструкторе одного из subinterpretators), с помощью дебаггера не получается, так как, когда выполняю программу пошагово, то она завершается нормально.

В общем у меня два вопроса:

1) Верно ли то, что приводится в статье?

2) Как всё-таки правильно (если это возможно) обеспечить параллельное выполнение пайтоновских скриптов (без блокировок) в коде `c++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как всё-таки правильно (если это возможно) обеспечить параллельное
>   выполнение пайтоновских скриптов (без блокировок) в коде c++?

А никак. В Питоне не обойти GIL. Если нужны несколько интерпретаторов в программе, то используйте проект:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/obasic/

Это интерпретатор правда не Питона, а Basic. Оформлен этот интерпретатор в виде отдельного С++ класса и все свои таблицы содержит в своем экземпляре класса. Соответственно, в программе пользователя можно иметь несколько (теоретически сколь угодно много) экземпляров класса интерпретатора, которые никак не зависят друг от друга. Соответственно, нет никаких GIL, можно запускать разные скрипты в разных экземплярах интерпретаторов. Конечно, если скрипты обращаются к одним и тем же структурам программы пользователя, то тут может понадобится синхронизация. Но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: в дополнение к тому, что выбрал ответ: действительно, в `python` не обойтись без `GIL`, однако, если нужен встаиваемый интерпритатор, то в этом плане, конечно, лучше использовать `lua` - легкий, быстрый, имеет `GIT` компилятор, имеет простой синтаксис и создан ровно для встраивания.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, наверное все-таки не GIT компилятор, а JIT компилятор? Кстати, использование JIT компилятора оно конечно ускоряет программу, но зато трудно сделать отладчик на уровне исходных кодов, так как связь между исполняемым кодом и исходным кодом разрывается.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, больно смотреть как Вы в одиночку сражаетесь с Lua. Серьезно, попробуйте Open Basic. Это такой же интерпретатор для встраивания. В качестве бонуса Вы получите техподдержку прямо на сайте stackoverflow, на русском языке от автора кода (меня). Если сравнивать с Lua, то это как если бы Вы писали самому Роберто Иерусалимскому в Рио-де-Жанейро на португальском и он бы Вам отвечал персонально. :-) Краткое описание Open Basic можно посмотреть в моем профиле.

Comment: да, JIT, просто опечатка

Comment: что же касается того как вам "больно смотреть как Вы в одиночку сражаетесь с Lua" - я извиняюсь, но что за бред вы несёте? Во-первых я с ним не сражаюсь, а использую. Во-вторых мне не нужно писать создателю lua, чтобы что-то выяснить - он хорошо документирован и мал сам по себе (не говоря о том, что на stackoverflow есть категория посвященная этому языку. В-третьих, lua используется во многих крупных проектах (и я не про дотку), например openresty - где, собственно, и используются его главные преимущества: лёгкость и простота, скорость (+jit) и расширяемость.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch просто Вы периодически задаете вопросы по Lua на stackoverflow, а в ответ тишина. :-) Никто из участников stackoverflow не применяет Lua и не может ничего посоветовать. Вот и создается впечатление одинокого рыцаря, в одиночку сражающегося с драконом. :-)

Comment: в этом плане вам стоит обращать внимание также и на комментарии: на все вопросы по lua кроме одного (а их было всего несколько штук) я получили ответы, хотя ответы не всегда публиковались как таковые (они были опубликованы в комментариях).